# How do I create a spring bean for a Java double primitive?

Tags: java, spring, double

I'd like to create a spring bean that holds the value of a double. Something like:

```
<bean id="doubleValue" value="3.7"/>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Declare it like this:

```
<bean id="doubleValue" class="java.lang.Double">
   <constructor-arg index="0" value="3.7"/>
</bean>
```

And use like this:

```
<bean id="someOtherBean" ...>
   <property name="value" ref="doubleValue"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: In case you want to shorten it a tiny bit, the `index` attribute of the `constructor-arg` element appears to be optional.

Answer (score 6):

It's also worth noting that depending on your need defining your own bean may not be the best bet for you.

```
<util:constant static-field="org.example.Constants.FOO"/>
```

is a good way to access a constant value stored in a class and default binders also work very well for conversions e.g.

```
<bean class="Foo" p:doubleValue="123.00"/>
```

I've found myself replacing many of my beans in this manner, coupled with a properties file defining my values (for reuse purposes).  What used to look like this

```
<bean id="d1" class="java.lang.Double">
  <constructor-arg value="3.7"/>
</bean>
<bean id="foo" class="Foo">
  <property name="doubleVal" ref="d1"/>
</bean>
```

gets refactored into this:

```
<bean
  id="propertyFile"
  class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
  p:location="classpath:my.properties"
/>
<bean id="foo" class="Foo" p:doubleVal="${d1}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a **Double**? any reason?

Answer (score 0):

Spring 2.5+

**You can define bean like this in Java config:**

```
@Configuration
public class BeanConfig {
    @Bean
    public Double doubleBean(){
        return  new Double(3.7);
    }
}
```

**You can use this bean like this in your program:**

```
@Autowired
Double doubleBean;

public void printDouble(){
    System.out.println(doubleBean); //sample usage
}
```